# Corda Upgradation to V4.6

Tags: java, corda

I am implementing a use case where I upgraded cordapp from V4.5 OS to V4.6 OS. But when I using Corda V4.6 with custom schema on PostgreSQL.

***I am facing the issue with the Custom Vault Query, getting errors with the below piece of code.***

Sample Code:

```
FieldInfo attribute1 = null;
            try {
                attribute1 = getField("attributeInCordaSchema", AttributeSchema.PersistentAttribute.class);
            }catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            final String attributeFromService = (String) inputMapObj.get("attribute");
            QueryCriteria generalCriteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.ALL);
            QueryCriteria attribute1Criteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(Builder.equal(attribute1, attributeFromService));
            QueryCriteria criteria = generalCriteria.and(attribute1Criteria);
            Vault.Page<OurState> results = getServiceHub().getVaultService().queryBy(OurState.class, criteria);
            List<StateAndRef<OurState>> matchingStates = results.getStates();
```

ERROR:

```
net.corda.core.node.services.VaultQueryException: An error occurred while attempting to query the vault: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet at net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService._queryBy(NodeVaultService.kt:646) ~[corda-node-4.6.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.node.services.VaultService$DefaultImpls.queryBy(VaultService.kt:436) ~[corda-core-4.6.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.api.VaultServiceInternal$DefaultImpls.queryBy(VaultServiceInternal.kt) ~[corda-node-4.6.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService.queryBy(NodeVaultService.kt:54) ~[corda-node-4.6.jar:?]
```

**Is the way of custom querying the vault has changed?**

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have your exact state on hand, I can try to give an example for 4.6.

As far as I know it hasn't changed, here's my go to example for a vault query using corda 4.6 from the obligation cordapp.

I like to query by the classname personally as that makes things a little simpler for me.

```java
            List<UUID> listOfLinearIds = Arrays.asList(stateLinearId.getId());
            QueryCriteria queryCriteria = new QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(null, listOfLinearIds);
            Vault.Page results = getServiceHub().getVaultService().queryBy(IOUState.class, queryCriteria);
            StateAndRef inputStateAndRefToSettle = (StateAndRef) results.getStates().get(0);
            IOUState inputStateToSettle = (IOUState) ((StateAndRef) results.getStates().get(0)).getState().getData();
```

source cordapp: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/obligation/flows/IOUSettleFlow.java#L57-L61

It's also worth mentioning that there's a lot of code examples for latest corda in the docs here: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/api-vault-query.html